# UITableView - Some Values change after scrolling

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, ios7, scroll

I found many question about this. But unfortunately couldn't find a solution for my issue.
My Code:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"DuelListCell";
DuelRequestsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

int row = [indexPath row];

cell.ReceiverName.text = _receiverFullName[row];
cell.ReceiverTeam.text = _receiverTeamName[row];

if ([_senderId[row] intValue] == [app.activeUser intValue]){

    if ([_duelStatusId[row] intValue] == 0){
        cell.ReceiverResult.hidden = YES;
        cell.ReceiverMessage.hidden = NO;
        cell.ReceiverMessage.text = @"Waiting";

        cell.ReceiverMessage.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:245.0/255.0 green:152.0/255.0 blue:41.0/255.0 alpha:1];

    }
    else if ([_duelStatusId[row] intValue] == 2){
        cell.ReceiverResult.hidden = YES;
        cell.ReceiverMessage.hidden = NO;
        cell.ReceiverMessage.text = @"Refused";

        cell.ReceiverMessage.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:245.0/255.0 green:29.0/255.0 blue:41.0/255.0 alpha:1];

    }


}else if ([_receiverId[row] intValue] == [app.activeUser intValue]){



    if ([_duelStatusId[row] intValue] == 0){

        cell.ReceiverResult.hidden = YES;
        cell.AcceptChallange.hidden = NO;

    }
    else if ([_duelStatusId[row] intValue] == 2){
        cell.ReceiverResult.hidden = YES;
        cell.ReceiverMessage.hidden = NO;
        cell.SenderMessage.text = @"You Refused";

        cell.SenderMessage.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:245.0/255.0 green:29.0/255.0 blue:41.0/255.0 alpha:1];
    }else if ([_duelStatusId[row] intValue] == 1){
        //NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Row: %d", row]);
    }
}

return cell;

}
```

When I scroll the table, Values are changing. I tried many different way, but could not find a solution and I am so confused at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was all about forgetting the else` end of the if-else statements.

Answer (score 0):

you should check that your cell is not nil and if it is, create a new one.

```
if (cell == nil) {

  cell = [[DuelRequestsTableViewCell alloc] initWithNib.....] ;
}
```

Comment: I tried **cell = [[DuelRequestsTableViewCell alloc] initWithNib:@"DuelListCell" bundle:nil];** But when I write **cell = [[DuelRequestsTableViewCell alloc] initwith** it offers initWithCoder, initWithFrame and initWithStyle, but no initWithNib. :(

Comment: I tried **cell = [[DuelRequestsTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];** But It did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

use this it is working

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"DuelListCell";  
DuelRequestsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell= [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:cellNibName owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    }
```

and set cell identifier here
[image]

Comment: What should I write instead of cellNibName? I wrote @"DuelListCell" but it did not work :(

Comment: put your cell xib name associated with your DuelRequestsTableViewCell

Comment: Is the xib name not @"DuelListCell"? I tried it but didn't work.

Comment: Do you have set CellIdentifier in cellxib?

Comment: in storyboard right? Yes I did it. It is DuelListCell. Thats why I use **static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"DuelListCell";**

Comment: I have already done this mate. Thats why I wrote **static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"DuelListCell";**